# Working with javascript and API exasperates me: Always Response 400

Tags: javascript, python, api, request

I am trying to work with an API (that provides data about movies in the media centers of german public broadcasting) but I can't get a single useful response.
I got an example code in javascript but since I dont know anything about that language I try to understand as much as I can and write an equivalent python program. Can someone tell me my mistake? The code should return a list of movies along with their duration and some similar information.

The original goes like:

`

```
const query = {
    queries: [
      {
        fields: ['title', 'topic'],
        query: 'sturm der liebe'
      },
      {
        fields: ['channel'],
        query: 'ard'
      }
    ],
    sortBy: 'timestamp',
    sortOrder: 'desc',
    future: false,
    offset: 0,
    size: 10,
    duration_min: 20,
    duration_max: 100
  };

  const queryString = JSON.stringify(query);  // I think this turns query into a json file

  const request = new XMLHttpRequest();  // here I start to loose the understanding
  const requestURL = 'https://mediathekviewweb.de/api/query';

  request.open("POST", requestURL);

  request.addEventListener('load', function (event) {
    let response;
    try {
      response = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
    } catch (e) { }
    if (request.status == 200 && typeof response != 'undefined') {
      for (let i = 0; i < response.result.results.length; i++) {
        let entry = response.result.results[i];
        let row = $('<tr>');
        row.append($('<td>').text(entry.channel));
        row.append($('<td>').text(entry.topic));
        row.append($('<td>').text(entry.title));
        row.append($('<td>').text(entry.description));
        row.append($('<td>').text(entry.url_video));
        $('#mediathek > tbody').append(row);
      }

      $('#responseText').text(JSON.stringify(response, null, 2));
    } else {
      if (response) {
        console.log(response.err);

        $('#errorText').html(response.err.join('</br>'));
      }
      else {
        $('#errorText').html(request.statusText + '</br>' + request.responseText);
      }
    }
  });

  request.send(queryString);
```

`

I started using *requests*:

`

```
import requests
import json

url = "https://mediathekviewweb.de/api/query"
answer = requests.post(url, json=queryString)
print(answer)
print(json.loads(answer.content))
```

`

Already in this minimal example *answer* returns "*<Response [400]>*" and the content is "*{'result': None, 'err': ['Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1']}*"

Can someone help me out? I didn't give a json, where does this error come from?

---

I get the same response when I try
`

```
import requests
import json

url = "https://mediathekviewweb.de/api/query"
query = {
         "queries": [],  // I want to search through all movies so this is left clear
         "sortBy": "timestamp",
         "sortOrder": "desc",
         "future": False,
         "offset": 0,
         "size": 1000,
         "duration_min": 90,
         "content-type": "text/plain"
         }

queryString = json.dumps(query)  # hopefully this is equivalent to JSON.stringify()
answer = requests.post(url, json=queryString)
print(answer)
print(json.loads(answer.content))
```

`
I actually think this extra code isn't even used by the program.

I don't know if thats the right direction, but I think the javascript programm first opens a request and then  in an other step inputs the data. I can't do that with the requests package as far as I know.

Comment: `Unexpected token o in JSON` usually means the JSON you are sending is `"[object Object]"` - which as you can see, is not valid JSON

Comment: I understand that, but I get the same output when I just send `answer = requests.post(url, json=queryString)` here I didn't send a JSON, did I?

Comment: `json=queryString` you use the word *json* there so ... who knows - I mean, what is `queryString`, where does it come from? if it's `const queryString = JSON.stringify(query);` then yes, you are sending JSON (correctly)

Comment: Sorry I meant I get the same error message when I just send `answer = requests.post(url)` so there is really no JSON, right? I also see the same message when I just open the website [https://mediathekviewweb.de/api/query](https://mediathekviewweb.de/api/query) in my browser.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use XMLHttpRequest. This adds to the confusion.

Here is the `fetch` option:

```js
const query = {
  queries: [
    {
      fields: ['title', 'topic'],
      query: 'sturm der liebe',
    },
    {
      fields: ['channel'],
      query: 'ard',
    },
  ],
  sortBy: 'timestamp',
  sortOrder: 'desc',
  future: false,
  offset: 0,
  size: 10,
  duration_min: 20,
  duration_max: 100,
};

const requestURL = 'https://mediathekviewweb.de/api/query';

fetch(requestURL, { method: 'POST', body: JSON.stringify(query) })
  .then((res) => res.json())
  .then((res) => {
    // success request logic
    console.log('response', res);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    // error handling
    console.error(error);
  });
```

Comment: Sorry looks like my post was unclear, the javascript code should work, it is the example code of the api's developer. I am trying to "translate" it to python cause I can't code javascript. My problems appear in the python code. I hope this clears things up.